# EhCache Replication with Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, ehcache

Is it possible to use EHCache replication over JMS with IBM's Websphere MQ 7.0? I have a working sample using ActiveMQ (out of the box) but am not sure how to configure EHCache to work with Websphere MQ.

Below is a sample of my working ehcache.xml and ActiveMQInitialContextFactory configuration for ActiveMQ.

_______________________________**ActiveMQ Sample**_____________________________

ehcache.xml

```
<!-- ActiveMQ configuration out of the box -->
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="initialContextFactoryName=com.hcsc.contextfactory.ActiveMQContextFactory,
        providerURL=tcp://LJGO4RAJ:61616,
        replicationTopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=topicConnectionFactory,
        getQueueConnectionFactoryBindingName=queueConnectionFactory,
        getQueueBindingName=ehcache,
        listenToTopic=true,
        replicationTopicBindingName=ehcache"
    propertySeparator="," />

<cache name="distributedCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000"
    eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheReplicatorFactory"
     properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, 
                     replicatePuts=true,
                     replicateUpdates=true,
                     replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,
                  replicateRemovals=true,                                                asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=500"
        propertySeparator="-" />

</cache>
```

**ActiveMQInitialContextFactory implementation (from ehcache.xml)**

```
public class ActiveMQContextFactory extends ActiveMQInitialContextFactory {

@Override
public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable environment)
        throws NamingException {

    Map<String, Object> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

    // Configure the Topic connection factory binding name
    String factoryBindingName = (String) environment
            .get(JMSUtil.TOPIC_CONNECTION_FACTORY_BINDING_NAME);
    try {
        data.put(factoryBindingName, createConnectionFactory(environment));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new NamingException("Error initialisating ConnectionFactory"
                + " with message " + e.getMessage());
    }

    String topicBindingName = (String) environment
            .get(JMSUtil.REPLICATION_TOPIC_BINDING_NAME);
    data.put(topicBindingName, createTopic(topicBindingName));

    // Configure queue connection factory binding name
    String getQueueConnectionfactoryBindingName = (String) environment
            .get(JMSUtil.GET_QUEUE_CONNECTION_FACTORY_BINDING_NAME);

    if (getQueueConnectionfactoryBindingName != null) {
        try {
            data.put(getQueueConnectionfactoryBindingName,
                    createConnectionFactory(environment));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new NamingException(
                    "Error initialisating TopicConnectionFactory with message "
                            + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    String getQueueBindingName = (String) environment
            .get(JMSUtil.GET_QUEUE_BINDING_NAME);
    if (getQueueBindingName != null) {
        data.put(getQueueBindingName, createQueue(getQueueBindingName));
    }

    return createContext(environment, data);
}

}
```

The above configuration works perfectly, but I need to convert it to use Websphere MQ. Below is what I have so far...

_______________________________**WebsphereMQ Sample**__________________________

**ehcache.xml**

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="initialContextFactoryName=com.hcsc.contextfactory.WebSphereMQContextFactory,
        providerURL=tcp://LJGO4RAJ:1415,
        replicationTopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=topicConnectionFactory,
        getQueueConnectionFactoryBindingName=queueConnectionFactory,
        getQueueBindingName=myqueue,
        listenToTopic=true,
        replicationTopicBindingName=ehcache"
    propertySeparator="," />

<cache name="distributedCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000"
    eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, 
                                            replicatePuts=true,
                                            replicateUpdates=true,
                                            replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,
                                            replicateRemovals=true,
                                            asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=500"
        propertySeparator="-" />

</cache>
```

**MQQueueConnectionFactory (I assume I need this similar to ActiveMQContextFactory)**

```
public class WebSphereMQContextFactory extends MQQueueConnectionFactory {

// TODO - NOT SURE HOW TO CONFIGURE THIS FOR EHCACHE?

}
```

I believe I will need a MQQueueConnectionFactory similar to how I created one for ActiveMQ, am I going in the right direction? I cannot find any sample code to achieve this.

Comment: The stack trace included there is an ActiveMQ stack - so MQ JMS would appear to be configure to be used.   The 'providerURL' there is pointing to the port that MQ is listening on for messaging operations.. MQ is NOT a JNDI service provider.  

You'll need to configure a JNDI repository with MQ JMS objects - and then make sure the MQ JMS classes are on the classpath (check the KnowledgeCentre here)

Comment: @Calanais you are indeed correct, the above stacktrace is coming from the ActiveMQ stack due to initialContextFactoryName=com.hcsc.contextfactory.ContextFactory. My ContextFactory.java class extends ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, so thats why we see my stacktrace. I will edit my post to better reflect my problem. Changes will be posted soon...

Comment: Just as a question.. why would you want to do this? Is it because you can't use RMI replication for some reason?

Comment: @Richard Nice question. That's another consideration I am looking at but started with JMS first since it was a newer supported technology by EHcache. Do you think RMI is an easier / more reliable replicated caching topology?

Comment: Oooh.. big question. Let me just say that I've worked on some VERY large systems that use EHCache and RMI replication. I think it's the fastest replication protocol. There is however a downside, which is that 'auto peer discovery' out of the box requires the use of multicast TCP. However, you can get around this by either manually telling each member of the cluster where all the other peers are, or by writing your own discovery code (I have examples).

Comment: We tried JGroups as a replication protocol too, but that was orders of magnitude slower. Are you using Spring?

Comment: @Richard Yep I am using Spring. I think I will trust you on this one since I am finding JMS implementation with Websphere quite troublesome. I have only glanced at the RMI specs from EHCaches documentation. Does that approach require the use of any broker services like ActiveMQ, Websphere, OpenMQ, etc.? Sorry for the high level question but was just curious.

Comment: No.. RMI replication with EHCache is Peer to Peer.

Comment: If you're using Spring..... (draws breath) For years and years Spring avoided the issue of distribution and left it up to us. But they've recently, and finally got around to addressing this deficiency. I haven't checked it out yet but you might want to :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/

It looks, on the face of it like they've settled on some god aweful redis solution.. But you never know it might be just what you need?

If you need any help with EHCache though.. If it can be done.. I've probably done it.. So just ask.

Comment: Cool, I think I will have a closer look at the RMI implementation for now and see if I can come up with a quick proof of concept. Thanks for the info! I'll be sure to update this post with my findings, and could be some more queries headed in your direction in the future :)

Comment: @Richard do you have any idea where I can find a simple working, downloadable RMI sample project? I cannot find a fully working sample from the EHCache site. Looks like they only provide outdated html views of each java class for their Unit tests.

Comment: I'll dig you something up..

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? It hasn't taken as long as I thought afterall.

Comment: I am using Springsource ToolSuite, but its basically the same as eclipse.

Comment: EDIT : Here is an eclipse project : https://ef01933c96932943ba7e03f763b0454f4a4b5fb6.googledrive.com/host/0BxWpugR7HDbnblJiMGxDMG5vLVU/
Import it, then run clean install on the maven pom, then right click on TestApplication and do 'run as java application'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71358/discussion-between-jason-and-richard).