# Ehcache jms replication websphereMQ

Tags: caching, replication, ibm-mq, ehcache

I'm trying to setup the Ehcache replication using JMS WebsphereMQ v7 as a provider. I did this replication using ActiveMQ and everthing is ok, but I'm trying to figure out which class I need to use to create a initialContext.

This is the current code using ActiveMQ and working good, I good it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571809/ehcache-replication-with-websphere-mq).

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect" 
dynamicConfig="true">
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="initialContextFactoryName=ca.toyota.testcache.cache.ActiveMQContextFactory,
    providerURL=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616,
    replicationTopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=topicConnectionFactory,
    getQueueConnectionFactoryBindingName=queueConnectionFactory,
    getQueueBindingName=ehcacheGetQueue,
    listenToTopic=true,
    replicationTopicBindingName=ehcache"
propertySeparator="," />


<cache name="cacheTest1" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
    eternal="false" 
    diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
    transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />

    <cacheEventListenerFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheReplicatorFactory"
 properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, 
                 replicatePuts=true,
                 replicateUpdates=true,
                 replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,
              replicateRemovals=true,                                                
              asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=500"
    propertySeparator="," />
</cache>
```

ActiveMQContextFactory.java:

```
    package ca.toyota.testcache.cache;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory;

import net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSUtil;
import net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ActiveMQContextFactory extends ActiveMQInitialContextFactory {
    @Override
    public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable environment)
            throws NamingException {

        Map<String, Object> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

        // Configure the Topic connection factory binding name
        String factoryBindingName = (String) environment
                .get(JMSUtil.TOPIC_CONNECTION_FACTORY_BINDING_NAME);
        try {
            data.put(factoryBindingName, createConnectionFactory(environment));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new NamingException("Error initialisating ConnectionFactory"
                    + " with message " + e.getMessage());
        }

        String topicBindingName = (String) environment
                .get(JMSUtil.REPLICATION_TOPIC_BINDING_NAME);
        data.put(topicBindingName, createTopic(topicBindingName));

        // Configure queue connection factory binding name
        String getQueueConnectionfactoryBindingName = (String) environment
                .get(JMSUtil.GET_QUEUE_CONNECTION_FACTORY_BINDING_NAME);

        if (getQueueConnectionfactoryBindingName != null) {
            try {
                data.put(getQueueConnectionfactoryBindingName,
                        createConnectionFactory(environment));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new NamingException(
                        "Error initialisating TopicConnectionFactory with message "
                                + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        String getQueueBindingName = (String) environment
                .get(JMSUtil.GET_QUEUE_BINDING_NAME);
        if (getQueueBindingName != null) {
            data.put(getQueueBindingName, createQueue(getQueueBindingName));
        }

        return createContext(environment, data);
    }

}
```

Finally my question is: Which InitialContextFactory I should use to work with WebpshereMQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For whom having the same problem, I'm almost 100% sure there is no way to use JMS replication on WAS.

After setup the ehcache replication using WebsphereMQ I'm getting the follow error:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Exception while creating JMS connections: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheManagerPeerProvider.init(JMSCacheManagerPeerProvider.java:193)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:479)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:270)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1116)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1092)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSCMUtils.methodNotPermittedException(JMSCMUtils.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.checkRestrictedMethod(JMSConnectionHandle.java:854)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.setExceptionListener(JMSConnectionHandle.java:353)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheManagerPeerProvider.init(JMSCacheManagerPeerProvider.java:162)
    ... 136 more
```

Looking for this problem I found the follow common issue:

**ehCache replication guide says:**
WebSphere Application Server prevents MessageListeners, which are not MDBs, from
being created in the container.
While this is a general Java EE limitation, most other app servers either are permissive
or can be configured to be permissive. WebSphere 4 worked, but 5 and 6 enforce the
restriction.
Accordingly, Ehcache together with JMS cannot be used with WebSphere 5 and 6.

**On Websphere 8 documentation** (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tmj_desap.html?lang=it) : 
*The section "Java Message Service (JMS) Requirements" of the J2EE specification gives a list of methods that must not be called in web and EJB containers:*

```
  javax.jms.Session method setMessageListener
  javax.jms.Session method getMessageListener
  javax.jms.Session method run
  javax.jms.QueueConnection method createConnectionConsumer
  javax.jms.TopicConnection method createConnectionConsumer
  javax.jms.TopicConnection method createDurableConnectionConsumer
  javax.jms.MessageConsumer method getMessageListener
  javax.jms.MessageConsumer method setMessageListener
  javax.jms.Connection setExceptionListener
  javax.jms.Connection stop
  javax.jms.Connection setClientID
```

***This method restriction is enforced in WebSphere Application Server by throwing a javax.jms.IllegalStateException exception.***

Comment: Is EHCache JMS spec-compliant? I do not see "replicationTopic" anything in thr JMS spec so I'm guessing no.  Also, are you trying to get MQ to use this or WAS? Because the question is tagged ibm-mq but the answer talks about WAS.